# While Loop suggestion?

Tags: java, while-loop

Write a while loop that selects and displays a random set of two numbers (1-99) that when added together are evenly divisible by 7. Continue until the user says they are "done".

I don't know how to makes those two random numbers divisible evenly with 7 
I have tried if statement but it still wouldn't work.

This is what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
    String answer="Yes";

    System.out.println("Run the program?");
    answer= scan.nextLine();


    while(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("done") )
    {
        int a=1;
        int b=1;
        a=(int) (Math.random()*99) + 1;
        b=(int) (Math.random()*99) + 1;
        if ((a + b) % 7 == 0) 
        {
            System.out.println(a + " + " + b + "= " +(a+b));
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
        answer= scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would prefer [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) because it's easier to read (and use). Then you can adjust `b` by the result of `a + b` modulo `7` (since that is the remainder). Something like,

```
Random rand = new Random();
while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
    int a = 1 + rand.nextInt(99);
    int b = 1 + rand.nextInt(99);
    // Updated based on @JimGarrison's comment.
    if (b < 7) {
        b = 7 - a;
    } else if (b > 93) {
        b = 98 - a;
    } else {
        b -= (a + b) % 7;
    }
    System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b));
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: When `a==2` and `b==1` after the initial random generation, `b` will end up being `-1`, failing the requirements.  Can fail any time the randomly chosen initial `b` is less than `7`.  Same problem at the other end (`b > 93`)

Comment: @JimGarrison I hadn't considered the edge cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since it random so the cases to get (a + b) % 7 != 0 may take in a lot.

So i think this will be little efficiency:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "Yes";

        System.out.println("Run the program?");
        answer = scan.nextLine();
        int LIMIT = 99;
        List<Integer> divisible7List = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Generate elements that divisible by 7 that less than 99 + 99
        int count = 1;
        int divisible7 = 7 * count;
        int maxDivisible7 = LIMIT + LIMIT;
        while (divisible7 < maxDivisible7) {
            divisible7List.add(divisible7);
            divisible7 = 7 * (++count);
        }

        int size = divisible7List.size();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            int idx = rand.nextInt(size - 1);
            int sumab = divisible7List.get(idx);
            int a = 1 + rand.nextInt(sumab);
            int b = sumab - a;

            sb.append(a);
            sb.append(" + ");
            sb.append(b);
            sb.append(" = ");
            sb.append(sumab);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            answer = scan.nextLine();
        }
```

In order to wait a + b fit your need, just pre-generate the need and find a and b.